# TFS 2015 Publish Artifact

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, msbuild

Under TFS 2015 under command line step I have :
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com

Under Arguments:
"MuSolution.sln" /build $(BuildConfiguration)

Where Release is configured build into  `..\bin\`
and Debug is configured to `..\bin\Debug\`

I checked and the

> $(BuildConfiguration)

is release and it builds for release
On Publish Build Artifacts step
Root is specified as $SomeRootFolder\MySolution where the bin folder gets written to

Contents are:

```
/bin/**
/MySolutionApp/Web.config
/MySolutionApp/Global.asax
/MySolutionApp/ApplicationInsights.config
```

Artifact 
MySolution

Artifact Folder gets created with nothing there.

I have tried **\bin** but everything including Debug folder gets written.

I need to have Artifact in this layout:

```
MySolution\bin
/MySolution/Web.config
/MySolution/Global.asax
/MySolution/ApplicationInsights.config
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use command line to build your project? How's your build definition like?

Answer (score 0):

First off, use the `Visual Studio Build` step -- it's designed to run Visual Studio properly.

Secondly, you'll need to pass in appropriate MSBuild arguments for your web application.
`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"` is a common set that will bundle up the application as a web deploy zip file.

`/p:OutDir=$(build.artifactstagingdirectory) /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true` should put an uncompressed version in `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`.

You may need to tweak these parameters a bit to get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`**\bin\**` copies all files recursively from any bin folder. You could try the following match patterns:

```
**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**

MySolutionApp\Web.config

MySolutionApp\Global.asax

MySolutionApp\ApplicationInsights.config
```

Answer (score 0):

In MysSolution.sln and in startup project created a publishing profile `MyReleasePublishProfile` with Release and Any CPU set along with Target Location where to drop Bin and rest of the files.

In TFS 2015 created MSBuild Visual Studio step and pointed at my solution `MySolution.sln` solution and set 
Restore NuGet Packages: `Checked`
Configuration : `Release`

Advanced:
 MSBuild `Version`
 MSBuild Version `Latest`
 MSBuild Architecture   `MSBuild x64`

MSBuild Arguments to:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyReleasePublishProfile
```

Hope this helps people like me who wanted a way to build this out.